# How to get rid of Google Play Store has stopped message

Tags: google-play-store, bugs

I keep on getting this message: "Google Play Store has stopped." I have tried deleting the Google Play app and could not install it from the web. The next day it reappeared. I keep getting this message:

[image]

How do I get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Good starting point is usually our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) – I wonder that this case isn't covered there. Usually steps are going to *Settings › Apps* (to the "All" tab if there's one), scroll to the app, enter its settings, then "clear cache". If that doesn't do the trick, "uninstall updates", "clear cache" again, reboot. Last resort: the same plus "delete data", then reboot. Very last resort, as usual, would be a factory reset.

Comment: Related: [Message: Unfortunately Google Play Store has stopped](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/145311/16575) // [Google Play Store force closing](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49869/16575)

Answer (score 0):

### Try clearing the app caches and app data of

- Google Play Services
- Google Services Framework
- Google Play Store

If that doesn't solve it, try this

### Settings->Apps->Google Play Store->Uninstall Updates->Ok

now restart the device and launch Google Play Store app.